# Specified argument was out of range C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, windows-server-2012

i am newbie in C#, so i dont know why in Windows 7 my application(program) works perfectly and on Windows Server 2012 i have this error when i trying to get message from client-side. C#.

Error:

> system.argumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: Size.
>   at system.net.sockets.networkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, int32 offset, int32 size)

Send function:

```
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text + "$");
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
serverStream.Flush();
```

Receive function:

```
NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
Console.WriteLine("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient);
```

Problem in this row:

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

and maybe here: **(int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize**

How to fix this, have any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize`?

Comment: I dont know, i dont change it...

Answer (score 2):

I only had to deal with TCP Sockets now, and I found this sample code, and got the same error message. I searched the web, and here's what I found:

Change this:

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

Into this:

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);
```

And if you are getting a similar error for the Client side, just check on the same `.Read()` section. Apply the same solution of using the `.Length` property.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you cast

```
clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize
```

to an int when it normally should already be an int? ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))?

And to what size is

```
byteFrom
```

initialized? It should be at least the value of ReceiveBufferSize. But be sure that the value does not change between initializing an the Read().

Comment: byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];

Comment: Are you using the default ReceiveBufferSize or did you change/increase it? If you did what did you increase it to?

Comment: No, i don't change it. Because i don't know where... its default.

Comment: This is a series of comments, not an answer (because the question *can't* be answered at this point).